# Backbone multiple listenTo

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I know the function listenTo and I need to apply it in a hard condition. I've an array and each entry into array is a reference to a collection.I need to wait that all collection are totally fetched. My fetch function collection  store data by reset function. And I listen to event reset.

```
var postTwitter= new Array(); 
var postInstagram= new Array();

var i=0;
    _.each(AttoriCollectionDb.models, function (model) {
        postTwitter[i]=new Posts();
        postTwitter[i].fetch({'user_id':model.get("id_twitter"),'type':'twitter'});
        postInstagram[i]=new Posts();
        postInstagram[i].fetch({'user_id':model.get("id_instagram"),'type':'instagram'});
        i++;

      });


      this.listenTo(postTwitter[0], 'reset', ok1);// now wait only one collection but I need wait all collection completely fetched.
```

In code above I wait only for a single collection reset,how can I listen to when all collection will have reset event?

Comment: On a side note you might want to have a look at how `_.each` works. You don't need to keep an index yourself, also you don'te even need it to access the collection's items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is my approach:

1) Add a custom event "reset:allPosts" to fire when all the Posts have fired "reset"

2) Gather the total of "reset" triggers you want to be called (all the Posts instagram + twitter). I named this "totalPosts"

3) Setup a scope variable "totalResetted", so you can incrementally add after a Post fires "reset"

4) After every "reset" fired, add one to the "totalResetted" and check if the "totalResetted" equals "totalPosts".  If it does equal, that means all the Posts have fired "reset"

Here's what I come up with:

```
var postTwitter= new Array(); 
var postInstagram= new Array();

var totalPosts= AttoriCollectionDb.models.length * 2; // Times two because we're adding Twitter and Instagram 
var totalResetted= 0;

var checkResetted = function() { 
  totalResetted++;
  if (totalPosts === totalResetted) this.trigger('reset:allPosts');
}

// When all posts are 'reset' then do something;
this.on('reset:allPosts', function(){ alert('all posts fired reset!!') });

var i=0;
var that = this;
    _.each(AttoriCollectionDb.models, function (model) {
        postTwitter[i]=new Posts();
        that.listenToOnce( postTwitter[i], 'reset', checkResetted);
        postTwitter[i].fetch({'user_id':model.get("id_twitter"),'type':'twitter'});

        postInstagram[i]=new Posts();
        that.listenToOnce( postInstagram[i], 'reset', checkResetted);
        postInstagram[i].fetch({'user_id':model.get("id_instagram"),'type':'instagram'});

        i++;

      });
```

Answer (score 1):

What about writing 'on' in Posts collection's initialize?

```
var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({initialize: function () {
    this.on('reset', ok1);
}});
```